# Inversible operator in Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Consider $\phi\in L^{\infty}[0, 2\pi]$. Let M be operator $L_2[0, 2\pi]\rightarrow L_2[0, 2\pi]$$$Mf = \phi f$$
In $L_2[0, 2\pi]$ we have topological basis ${e^{inx}}, n\in \mathbb Z$.

$L_2[0, 2\pi] = H_+\oplus H_-$, where $H_+ = <e^{inx}, n \geq 0>, H_- = <e^{inx}, n < 0>$

Let T be operator $H_+ \rightarrow H_+, Tf = P_+(Mf)$, where $P_+$ is projector $H\rightarrow H_+$.

I need to prove that if M is not inversible then T is not inversible.

I proved that $M^* = M$.

Also proved that A is inversible $<-> \exists c>0\hspace{2mm} \forall x\hspace{2mm} (||Ax|| \geq c||x|| \hspace{2mm}\&\&\hspace{2mm} ||A^*x|| \geq c||x||)$.

Cant find $T^*$.Got stucked any help is welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with the half of the question that no longer exists: $M$ invertible does not imply $T$ invertible. Say $\phi=e_{-2}$. Then $M$ is invertible. But if $f=e_1$ then $Tf=P(e_{-1})=0$, so $T$ is not invertible.

On the other hand $T$ invertible does imply $M$ invertible. Suppose $M$ is not invertible. Let $\epsilon>0$, and set $$E=\{x:|\phi(x)|<\epsilon\}.$$
Then $m(E)>0$, since otherwise $\phi$ would be invertible in $L^\infty$ and hence $M$ would be invertible.

Note that $||\chi_E||=m(E)^{1/2}$ and $||M\chi_E||<\epsilon||\chi_E||$. That doesn't say immediately that $T$ is not invertible, because $\chi_E\notin H_+$. But if we apply a right shift we get something that's almost in $H_+$: For positive integers $N$ define $$f_N=P(e_N\chi_E).$$Then $f_N\in H_+$, and $$||f_N-e_N\chi_N||\to0\quad(N\to\infty).$$Hence $$||f_N||\to m(E)^{1/2}>0$$and $$||Tf_N||\le2\epsilon||f_N||$$for large $N$. So $T$ is not invertible.

Comment: Thats true. But I cant even prove that if inversible then M is inversible.

Comment: @SaveMyLife Ok, see edit.